# Maximal abelian subgroups of an extraspecial group of order $2^{2m+1}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I've found a proof of the structure of maximal abelian normal subgroups of an extraspecial group of order $2^{2m+1}$ in the book "Endlichen Gruppen I" by B. Huppert but there is a part of the proof I don't quite understand.

Assume $G=\mathcal{D_{1}}∗\cdots∗\mathcal{D_{m−1}}∗\mathcal{Q}$
(the central product of $m−1$
dihedral groups of order $8$
and quaternion). Then take $U$
a maximal abelian normal subgroup and decompose the element $a\in U$
into a product of two elements, i.e., $a=a_{1}a_{2}$
with $a_{1}\in\mathcal{D_{1}}∗\cdots∗\mathcal{D_{m−1}}$
and $a_{2}\in\mathcal{Q}.$
These elements are uniquely determined up to a factor of $Z(G).$
Then the subgroups $U_{i}$
are defined as the "product of all $a_{i},i=1,2$"
respectively, where each of the $a_{i}$
picked in their respective groups, and this is the part I don't catch. Does it mean $U_{i}$
is generated by $a_{i}$? Is $U_{i}$
generated by the product of some $a_{i}^{(1)},a_{i}^{(2)},\dots,a_{i}^{(r)}$? I don't understand the definition of the groups $U_{i}.$

I would greatly appreciate any help or idea.

Comment: It might be helpful if you reproduced a verbatim quote of the text in question, possible as an image. Or at least specify the exact place (section / page) in Huppert's book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems to refer to part (b) of Satz 13.8 on pages 355 and 356.

Reading the text carefully there, the idea is that you take all $a\in U$ and split each into $a_1\cdot a_2$. Then you define $U_1$ as the group generated by all the $a_1$ obtained this way, and similarly $U_2$ as generated by all the $a_2$.

Huppert then states that with this definition, $U_1$ is an abelian normal subgroup of the central product $\mathcal{D}_1\dots \mathcal{D}_{m-1}$ while $U_2$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $\mathcal{Q}$. And indeed $U\leq U_1 U_2$ and $U_1\cap U_2\leq Z(G)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! and sorry for not referencing the part. However, how does Huppert know that the order of $U_{1}$ has $2^{m}$ as an upper bound and similarly the order $U_{2}$ has $2^{2}.$ Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: $U_2$ is a normal abelian subgroup of $\mathcal{Q}$, which has order 8 and is not abelian, so obviously $|U_2|\leq 4$. For $U_1$: each $\mathcal{D}_i$ has a maximal abelian normal subgroup of order 4, so if this was a *direct* product that would give a normal group of size $4^{m-1}$. However, it is a central product, and the center has size $2$ in all these groups. From there you can work it out (informally, each factor contributes a factor 2, and one 2 more for the center, so $2^{m-1}\cdot 2=2^m$).

Comment: Ok, thank you! So the idea in the case of the $\mathcal{D}_{i}$ would be that each of them contributes with two elements not in the center and then you just have to multiply by 2 that quantity which is the order of the center?